# JOINs not using indexes in a predictable manner

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing, left-join

Say I have three tables.

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE movies_actors (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    movie_id INT,
    actor_id INT,
    current_salary_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY movie_id (movie_id),
    KEY actor_id (actor_id),
    KEY current_salary_id (current_salary_id)
);

CREATE TABLE movies_actors_salaries (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    actor_id INT,
    compensation_type ENUM('salary','hourly','commission','lumpsum'),
    amount DECIMAL(9,2),
    date_agreed_upon DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY actor_id (actor_id)
);
```

I'm trying to JOIN the tables to do some queries and indexes are very sporadically being used and I don't know why.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM movies m
JOIN movies_actors ma ON m.id = ma.movie_id
JOIN movies_actors_salaries mas ON ma.current_salary_id = mas.id;
```

If I do an EXPLAIN on that the Extra column for the ma table does not say "Using index". It doesn't matter if I do a `LEFT JOIN movies_actors_salaries` or a `JOIN movies_actors_salaries` - it's just not being used. Which I don't understand because m.id is the PRIMARY KEY for the movies table and ma.movie_id is a KEY.

I tried another query as well:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM movies m
JOIN movies_actors ma ON m.id = ma.movie_id
JOIN movies_actors_salaries mas ON ma.id = mas.actor_id;
```

If I do an EXPLAIN on that the Extra column for the ma table does not say "Using index" but if I do a `LEFT JOIN movies_actors_salaries` instead of `JOIN` the index does get used. Which again, I don't understand - why does the index the movie_actor table is using depend on the way I'm joining the movies_actors_salaries table?

Honestly, I don't understand any of this. It seems to me that the Extra column for all four (ie. the above two with a `JOIN movies_actors_salaries` and with a `LEFT JOIN movies_actors_salaries`) when an EXPLAIN is done should say "Using index".

I'm using Percona MySQL 5.5.35-33.0. Any ideas?

Comment: how many rows ya got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of greater concern than rows=1 and `Using where` for `ma` seen here:

```
mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(m.id) FROM movies m JOIN movies_actors ma ON m.id = ma.movie_id JOIN movies_actors_salaries mas ON ma.current_salary_id = mas.id;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys              | key     | key_len | ref                               | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ma    | ALL    | movie_id,current_salary_id | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                              |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mas   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY | 4       | so_gibberish.ma.current_salary_id |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY | 4       | so_gibberish.ma.movie_id          |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

**is a drop of last key seen here:**

```
-- drop table movies_actors;
CREATE TABLE movies_actors (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    movie_id INT,
    actor_id INT,
    current_salary_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY movie_id (movie_id),
    KEY actor_id (actor_id)
    -- KEY current_salary_id (current_salary_id)
);
```

**resulting in a new dreadful** `explain` with rows=1024 and `Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)` or a `using filesort` or a `using temporary` seen here after the above schema change and jamming rows in:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mas   | index  | PRIMARY       | actor_id | 5       | NULL                     |    1 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ma    | ALL    | movie_id      | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                     | 1024 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | so_gibberish.ma.movie_id |    1 | Using index                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

### The Takeaway

`Explain` is cryptic, as if you don't know, but the fact that your row count is low should be soothing compared to the alternatives just mentioned (ie: 1k rows and filesorts, temp tables).

Explain also lies. It is a Whimsical Fantasy Land, expected to render a few lines in split seconds, though when `Explain` is removed, it changes course based on realities on the ground.

I can have 1 row in `movies_actors_salaries` that would match your join, the Using index would suggest `mas` uses it, but I guarantee you it doesn't due to this [Manual Page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) extract:

> Indexes are less important for queries on small tables, or big tables
>   where report queries process most or all of the rows. When a query
>   needs to access most of the rows, reading sequentially is faster than
>   working through an index. Sequential reads minimize disk seeks, even
>   if not all the rows are needed for the query.

So you are good to go. Keep an eye on the `Explain` rowcount, and the use of filesorts and temporary warnings.